# nytprofhtml seem to ignore module named DB

Tags: perl, devel-nytprof

I'm trying to profile a big application that contains a module creatively named `DB`. After running it under `-d:NYTProf` and calling `nytprofhtml`,  both without any additional switches or related environment variables, I get usual `nytprof` directory with HTML output. However it seems that due to some internal logic any output related to my module `DB` is severely mangled. Just to make sure, `DB` is pure Perl.

1. Top and all subroutines list: while other function links point to relevant `-pm-NN-line.html` file, links to subs from `DB` point to entry script instead.
2. "line" link in "Source Code Files" section does point to `DB-pm-NN-line.html` and it does exists, but unlike all other files it doesn't have "Statements" table inside and "Line" table have absolutely no lines of code, only summary of calls.

Actually, here's a small example:

```
# main.pl
use lib '.';
use DB;

for (1..10) {
    print DB::do_stuff();
}

# DB.pm
package DB;

sub do_stuff {
    my $a = 1;
    my $b = 2;
    my $c = $a + $b;

   return $c;
}

1;
```

Try running `perl -d:NYTProf main.pl`, then `nytprofhtml` and then inspect `nytprof/DB-pm-8-line.html`.

I don't know if it happens because NYTProf itself have internal module named `DB` or it handles modules starting with DB in some magical way - I've noticed output for functions from `DBI` looks somewhat different too.

Is there a way to change/disable this behavior short of renaming my `DB` module?

Comment: See `DB - programmatic interface to the Perl debugging API` https://perldoc.perl.org/DB.html - it's a core module that's probably used by NYTProf. It would be best to rename your module

Comment: That's hardly an option with codebase nearing 10Mb and with pretty convoluted inheritance and dynamic loading. Anyway, the name is very generic and that's exactly why it is expected to be encountered in the wild, so if D::NYTP have it msihandling hardcoded - that'd be really bad.

Comment: DB isn't just a random module, it's effectively part of the core language, like `strict` or `IO::Handle`. NYTProf is right to use that infrastructure. Yes, your module might generally work but this kind of naming clash has similar problems to creating subroutines called `print`, `select`, or `say`. Renaming your module is the most sensible choice, and should be manageable with a few regexes. I generally prevent these kinds of problems by namespacing internal modules under some unique identifier, e.g. like `AMON::DB`.

Answer (score 3):

> That's hardly an option

You don't really have an option. The special `DB` package and the associated `Devel::` namespace are coded into the perl compiler / interpreter. Unless you want to do without any debugging facilities altogether and live in fear of any mysterious unquantifiable side effects then you must refactor your code to rename your proprietary `DB` library

> Anyway, the name is very generic and that's exactly why it is expected to be encountered

On the contrary, `Devel::NYTProf` is bound to use the existing core package `DB`. It's precisely because it is a very generic identifier that an engineer should reject it as a choice for production code, which could be required to work with pre-existing third-party code at any point

> a module creatively named `DB`

This belies your own support of the choice. `DB`has been a core module since v5.6 in 2000, and anything already in CPAN should have been off the cards from the start. I feel certain that the clash of namespaces must been discovered before now. Please don't be someone else who just sweeps the issue under the carpet

Remember that, as it stands, any code you are now putting in the `DB` package is sharing space with everything that perl has already put there. It is astonishing that you are not experiencing strange and inexplicable symptoms already

I don't see that it's too big a task to fix this as long as you have a proper test suite for your 10MB of Perl code. If you don't, then hopefully you will at least not make the same mistakes again